# Create a C++ program that outputs the sum and individual digits

Tags: c++

So, I'm struggling with a small coding problem. We're using a while or do while loop to and inputting a series of numbers and outputting the sum as well as the individual numbers.

For example if we put in 123 it should output as "1 2 3"  and the total should amount to 6

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        cout << "Enter a number";
        int individual_number, input_num, sum;
        cin >> input_num;
        cout << endl;
        do
        {
                individual_number = input_num % 10; 
                sum += individual_number;
                input_num = input_num / 10;

        } while (input_num > 0);

        cout << "The sum is: " << sum << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

The code outputs the sum but it doesn't separate the numbers. I.e. if I input 123, it will just output the sum and not "1 2 3"

Comment: You can use a container `list` or `vector` and then insert `individual_number` into them. Then outside loop just print the entries

Comment: Because you didn't print it :-|

Comment: *individual_number = input_num % 10;* -- Start with this.  Here is the digit, so where/when do you store it so that it can be printed later?  Also some advice -- if you know that the problem was "where do I store the digit for later use?", then you should state that as part of the question.  Otherwise it looks like you are putting very little effort in first figuring out what the problem is (the solution to the problem is a different story).

Comment: So what's the problem to add `std::cout << individual_number << ' ';` inside the loop after you calculated it?

Comment: Don't forget to initialize `sum`!

Comment: I tried that, but that outputs it backwards

Comment: Then store the individual digits somewhere (e.g. in a vector) and print them in reverse order.

Comment: Well, we aren't being taught about vectors yet, but I guess I gotta self teach yet again

Answer (score 1):

Below is the working example that shows what you want.

**Version 1**: Using `istringstream`

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include<sstream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
   
    int individual_number = 0,  sum = 0;//these are local built in types so initialize them
    char c;//for reading char
    std::string input_num;
    
    std::cin >> input_num;

    std::istringstream ss(input_num);
 
    
    while(ss >> c)
    {
        individual_number = c -'0';
        std::cout<<individual_number<<" ";
        sum+= individual_number;
    }
    std::cout<<"total amount: "<<sum<<std::endl;
   // std::cout<<"The sum comes out to be: "<<sum<<std::endl;
    
    
    
  return 0;
}
```

**Version 2**: Without `istringstream`

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
   
    int individual_number = 0,  sum = 0;//these are local built in types so initialize them
  
    std::string input_num;
    
    std::cin >> input_num;
    
    for(char c : input_num)
    {
        individual_number = c -'0';
        std::cout<<individual_number<<" ";
        sum+= individual_number;
    }
    std::cout<<"total amount: "<<sum<<std::endl;
   // std::cout<<"The sum comes out to be: "<<sum<<std::endl;
    
    
    
  return 0;
}
```

**Version 3**: Without any loops

```
#include <iostream>
int findDigit(int passed_num, int currentSum)
{
    
    int lastDigit;
  
    
    if (passed_num == 0) {
     
        return currentSum;
    }
 
    // find the last didit
    lastDigit = passed_num % 10;
    
    currentSum+= lastDigit;
  
   //call findDigit() repeatedly
    currentSum = findDigit(passed_num / 10, currentSum);
  
    std::cout<<lastDigit<<" ";
    
    return currentSum;
}
  
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    int input_num, sum;
    std::cin>>input_num;
    
    sum = findDigit(input_num, 0);
    
    std::cout<<"sum is: "<<sum<<std::endl;
    
     std::cout << "Enter another number: ";
     std::cin>>input_num;
    
    sum = findDigit(input_num, 0);
     std::cout<<"sum is: "<<sum<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple solution using a string to hold the original value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   int individual_number, input_num, sum;
   input_num = 123;
   std::string numStr = std::to_string(input_num);     
   std::cout << std::endl;

   sum = 0;
   do
   {
       individual_number = input_num % 10; 
       sum += individual_number;
       input_num = input_num / 10;
   } while (input_num > 0);

   std::cout << "The sum is: " << sum << std::endl;

   // Copies the string to the output
   for (auto ch : numStr)
     std::cout << ch << " ";
}
```

Output:

```
The sum is: 6
1 2 3
```